# .NET Core waiting for localhost when starting application

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have just created a new web app in Visual Studio 2017. For some reason when I try to start it, it just shows a white web browser with a waiting for localhost message.

In the debug output, I can see this exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll

However, I am unsure on what actually caused it?

When I debugged my startup.cs, there were no exceptions caused.

The exception occurs after BuildWebHost runs in my Program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("NLog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();

    var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(SDR_Logs.ClassLibrary.Globals.ApplicationGlobals.ConnectionString);
    LogManager.Configuration.Variables["connectionString"] = connectionString;
    try
    {
        logger.Debug("init main");
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //NLog: catch setup errors
        logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
        NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
    }
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
     WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseKestrel(options => options.AddServerHeader = false)
        //.UseConfiguration(Configuration)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.ClearProviders();
        })
        .UseNLog()
        .Build();
```

Is it possible to see more details on what this invalid operation is?

Comment: Can you try switching the debugging from IIS Express to your application? Do you still get an error?

Comment: If I remove use Kestrel then it works for some reason.

Comment: What machine are you using?  Is this first time using machine?  The logger is the serial port.  Did you connect a terminal like putty to serial port to view any error messages?

Comment: Kestrel is a web server the can replace IIS.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows

Comment: I cannot change from IIS Express to my application as if I do that, an exception will happen. This is not the first time using this machine.

Comment: My previous project used Kestrel without any issues. Not sure why this is an issue now

Comment: Did you try enabling break on caught exception for standard libraries in the exceptions window.  Ctrl alt e

Comment: @Jason I see. Turns out I can run it if I remove Kestrel. Can you put yours as the answer?

Comment: @JianYA, I can put it as the answer but I'd like to understand if I was the exception settings that helped you first. You were the person that suggested removing UseKestrel.

Comment: @Jason it helped me understand what was the problem. I never knew I could do that before. It said I was running an IIS process but was not configured to use IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you navigate to *Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings* (`Ctrl Alt E`) you can enable *Break When Thrown* for *Common Language Runtime Exceptions*.

[image]
[image]

This will break execution if there is an exception within the libraries you are using and might help shed some light on the issue.

When you are done you can reset the default settings by right clicking and selecting *Restore Defaults*.

[image]